# Gnus auth with username being prepended to domain

Tags: email, emacs, imap, authentication

I'm trying to solve the problem of Gnus asking you to type a username which it then prepends to the IMAP domain, i.e. preventing Gnus from making username typed at prompt `foo@bar.com` into `foo@bar.com@mail.bar.com`.

All the guides I've read online specify something like this for setting up login credentials:

> Place a line like the following in ~/.authinfo
>
> `machine imap.gmail.com login your-name@gmail.com password your-password port 993`

Following that, I added a string that looks like this:

`machine mail.foo.com login me@foo.com port 993`

This gets me good behavior (prompt for password only), but still prepends the whole username to the machine address. Worse, when I try to change something and repeat the login, I get an error `Wrong type argument: wholenump, nil`.

My `gnus.el` file has the following for IMAP:

```
; IMAP
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "mymail"
               (nnimap-address "mail.bar.com")
               (nnimap-server-port 993)
               (nnimap-stream ssl)))
```

Comment: In my numerous attempts at setting up Wanderlust, I came across something similar with a separate authorization file -- I ended up using something like this directly in my configuration file without needing a separate authorization file -- perhaps the regular gnu email is similar:  `(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("mail.msn.com" 587 "user-name" "password")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt is hard-coded in the source (`nnimap.el`):

```lisp
(defun nnimap-credentials (address ports user)
  (let* ((auth-source-creation-prompts
          '((user  . "IMAP user at %h: ")
            (secret . "IMAP password for %u@%h: ")))
         (found (nth 0 (auth-source-search :max 1
                                           :host address
                                           :port ports
                                           :user user
                                           :require '(:user :secret)
                                           :create t))))
    (if found
        (list (plist-get found :user)
          (let ((secret (plist-get found :secret)))
        (if (functionp secret)
            (funcall secret)
          secret))
          (plist-get found :save-function))
      nil)))
```

So it seems like the only way to change this is to redefine the function and modify the prompt to be just `"IMAP password for %u: "`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read elisp too well, but is this snippet actually appending the whole server to the input username?

Comment: Yes, it is. `%u` stands for the username, and `%h` stands for the server hostname.

Comment: It seems like the best way to take care of this is to advise the function. How would I go about doing that? (The emacswiki is not so clear about this for more complicated functions.)